# "I am curious what you think" or "I am curious about what you think"?

Tags: prepositions, subordinate-clauses

"What you think" is the object in the sentence, while *what* is a pronoun, so it should be "I am curious about something", not "I am curious something"?

Comment: "what you think" is a noun phrase, but ***to be curious*** isn't a transitive verb, so you must include preposition ***about***, OR use an infinitive-based complement: *I'm curious **to know** what you think.*

Comment: Perhaps there is confusion involving it-clefted sentences such as 'It is curious what some people get up to.' Or perhaps involving tightly paired independent clauses 'I am curious: what _is_ in the Gospel of Mark?'

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences sound fine to me.

> - I am curious about what you think.

In this version, "what you think" is another way of saying "your opinion" (or "your thoughts"). It could be rephrased as "I am curious about your opinion".

> - I am curious what you think.

This sounds like a variant of "I wonder what you think". It feels casual/colloquial, and may be what linguists call a syntactic blend (mixture of two constructions).

You are correct that an ordinary noun phrase cannot follow "curious" without a preposition:

- *I am curious your opinion.

In this case, "what you think" can be interpreted as an interrogative complement clause. In a conversation, I would be surprised to hear a "that"-clause, but not interrogative clauses:

- I am curious why they did that.
- I am curious whether they finished it.
- *I am curious that they finished it.

See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158607/is-curious-if-improper-to-use-compared-to-alternatives-such-as-curious-as-to

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions can be omitted in some idiomatic phrases. For example, "*I know John*" can mean various things depending on the context, ranging from you knowing the person named really well as a friend, in some other capacity, or maybe just enough to identify who is being spoken about. Context determines the meaning, whereas "*I know of John*" suggests only an awareness of their existence and "*I know about John*" may suggest you know about a matter relating to them, not necessarily knowing them personally. Choosing the right preposition (or choosing to omit one) is important.

Your example of "I am curious what you think" may be acceptable in some situations, depending on what follows, or what is implied. Presumably, you've already established a topic of conversation, so you are in effect asking "*I am curious what you think **about** [the subject we are discussing]*". It would be clumsy to use the same preposition twice and say "*I'm curious about what you think about this*".

But there are other options. You could say:

- I'm curious *as to* what you think
- I'm curious to know what you think

In this instance, I would disregard results from ngrams as they will be highly misleading. The results would be meaningless because the two phrases are not interchangeable. One would not say, for example, "*I'm curious to know science*", but you might say you were curious *about* it. If two phrases are not the same, you cannot compare their usage.

Answer (score 1):

These are both OK to say.

You might say

> "I am curious what you think"

immediately after sharing some new information with the listener, or reporting another person's opinion on a topic.  You are asking for their opinion on that information or topic.

> "I am curious about what you think"

Can mean the same, but might also be a more general question - not about a specific topic.   If the speaker is asking about a specific piece of information or topic that was just discussed, they might say this with "here" it the end:  "**I'm curious about what you think here.**"

Answer (score 0):

The correct version out of the two is "I am curious about what you think"

The reason is: 'what you think' is the subject matter of the curiosity.
About is a word that conveys subject matter.

Answer (score -1):

This looks better to me
`I am curious to know what you think.`

Moreover the correct sentence is `I am curious about what you think"?`

Comment: The question is asking whether the word "about" should be included in the sentence or not. While you can offer alternatives, you should answer the original question and justify why your alternative is better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There's been [a huge usage shift over the past couple of centuries. These days we're usually ***curious about*** what we used to be ***curious to know...***

[image]

So even though it sounds a bit "sloppy / casual" to me, *I am curious about what you think* is much more common today than *I am curious to know what you think*. But *I am curious what you think* isn't (yet?) acceptable - you need either a preposition or an infinitive-based construction if you want to attach a complement to *be curious*.